# XMLNodeList not retrieving right Nodes

Tags: c#, xml, xaml

I am creating application to make Mod Menu's for Modern Warfare 3 (XRPC). I am making it customisable with XML, i have created an Example XML.

```
<MenuFile>
<Credits>
    <Author>Callum Carmicheal</Author>
    <Name>Sample</Name>
    <Version>0.1</Version>
</Credits>

<InfoBar>
    <Text>Created by ..., Enjoy</Text>
</InfoBar>

<Menu>

    <Main>
        <Header> 
            <Name>Main Menu</Name>
        </Header>

        <Item>
            <Name>Enable Cheats</Name>
            <Function>
                <Menu>Mods</Menu>
            </Function>
            <Ignore>false</Ignore>
        </Item>

        <Item>
            <Name> </Name>
            <Function> </Function>
            <Ignore>True</Ignore>
        </Item>

        <Item>
            <Name></Name>
            <Function></Function>
            <Ignore>True</Ignore>
        </Item>

        <Item>
            <Name></Name>
            <Function></Function>
            <Ignore>True</Ignore>
        </Item>

        <Item>
            <Name></Name>
            <Function></Function>
            <Ignore>True</Ignore>
        </Item>

        <Item>
            <Name></Name>
            <Function></Function>
            <Ignore>True</Ignore>
        </Item>

        <Item>
            <Name></Name>
            <Function></Function>
            <Ignore>True</Ignore>
        </Item>
    </Main>

    <Mods>
        <Header>
            <Name>Mods</Name>
        </Header>

        <Item>
            <Name>Enable Cheats</Name>
            <Function>
                <Dvar>sv_cheats 1</Dvar>
            </Function>
            <Ignore>false</Ignore>
        </Item>

        <Item>
            <Name></Name>
            <Function></Function>
            <Ignore>True</Ignore>
        </Item>

        <Item>
            <Name></Name>
            <Function></Function>
            <Ignore>True</Ignore>
        </Item>

        <Item>
            <Name></Name>
            <Function></Function>
            <Ignore>True</Ignore>
        </Item>

        <Item>
            <Name></Name>
            <Function></Function>
            <Ignore>True</Ignore>
        </Item>

        <Item>
            <Name></Name>
            <Function></Function>
            <Ignore>True</Ignore>
        </Item>
    </Mods>

</Menu>

</MenuFile>
```

This is the markup for the Menu's, i have created some c# Code

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("menu.xml")); // suppose that myXmlString contains "<Names>...</Names>"

        XmlNode credits_author = xml.SelectSingleNode("/MenuFile/Credits/Author");
        XmlNode credits_name = xml.SelectSingleNode("/MenuFile/Credits/Name");
        XmlNode credits_version = xml.SelectSingleNode("/MenuFile/Credits/Version");
        Log("Credits(Author): " + credits_author.InnerText);
        Log("Credits(Name): " + credits_name.InnerText);
        Log("Credits(Version): " + credits_version.InnerText);

        XmlNode InfoBar = xml.SelectSingleNode("/MenuFile/InfoBar/Text");
        Log("");
        Log("InfoBar Text: " + InfoBar.InnerText);

        Log("");
        Log("Menus");

        XmlNodeList Menus = xml.SelectNodes("/MenuFile/Menu");
        // This returns 
        //   /MenuFile/Menu not /MenuFile/Menu/MainMenu....
        // it should loop through MainMenu, Mods...
        foreach (XmlNode MenuItem in Menus) {
            Log("\t Menu: " + MenuItem.Name); // Main should me MainMenu or Mods

            XmlNodeList Items = xml.SelectNodes("/MenuFile/Menu/" + MenuItem.Name);
            foreach (XmlNode mi in Items) {
                if (mi.Name == "Header") {
                    string xpath = FindXPath(mi);
                    string Header = xml.SelectSingleNode("/MenuFile/Menu/" + MenuItem.Name + "/Header/Name").InnerText;
                    Log("\t\t Header: " + Header);
                }
                else if (mi.Name == "Item") {
                    string Name = "";
                    string ignore = "";
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

But the problem is when trying to retrieve the MenuList/Menu's children nodes, it returns MenuList/Menu itself i have no clue.
I've tried debugging but the results are the same, can anyone see my error in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are looping through the Menu nodes, not Main or Mods nodes:

```
XmlNodeList Menus = xml.SelectNodes("/MenuFile/Menu");
foreach (XmlNode MenuItem in Menus) {
```

will always return the outer Menu nodes.

To fetch the Main/Mods nodes use the following:

```
XmlNodeList menus = xml.SelectNodes("/MenuFile/Menu/*");
foreach (XmlNode menuItem in menus) {
```

Also, rather just fetch 'Header' and 'Items' nodes directly rather than performing an unnecessary "if":

```
XmlNode headerItem = menuItem.SelectSingleNode("Header");
...
XmlNodeList items = menuItem.SelectNodes("Item");
foreach (XmlNode item in items) {
   ...
```